# Preload Asynchronous Image to show in UIimageview offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I write app to use picture from url to show in UIimageview but I run in iPhone imageview do not show picture this is my code

```
 __block UIImage *pic1,*pic2,*pic3;
UIImageView *p1,*p2,*p3;
NSString *strImgURLAsString = mylink;
NSString *strImgURLAsString2 = mylink2;

[strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];

[strImgURLAsString2 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
 NSURL *imgURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString2];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"downloaded");
        pic1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];     
}];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            NSLog(@"downloaded");
            pic2 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];     
    }];
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        NSLog(@"downloaded");
        pic1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];     
}];

if([name isEqualToString:@"des1"])// it is restoration of viewcontroller{
    [p1 setImage:pic1];   
}
else if ([name isEqualToString:@"des2"])// it is restoration of viewcontroller{
 [p1 setImage:pic2];   
}
```

Comment: you should write if condition in your block to set image

Comment: u are downloading image in asynchronous so when image downloading below code of set image execute (because it's in main thread and image download in background thread ) and when set image code execute pic1 & pic2 may b nil so image not set

Comment: Yeah I change to use with AFnetworking and solved this problem with myself

Answer (score -1):

u are set image before it download 
set image in block as show below

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    NSLog(@"downloaded");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    pic1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];     
if([name isEqualToString:@"des1"]){
[p1 setImage:pic1];   
        });

}

}];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{        }) use for load image on main thread because u download image asynchronous
```

Comment: I use it before but I want to download picture all before show image (in if condition use in restoration ID of UIviewcontroller ) I will Edited in my question

Comment: as per ur current code u are downloading image asynchronous. and u are set image out side of completion block . so  [p1 setImage:pic1]; set image before image download from URL